# verb form allowed after 'other than'

Tags: grammar

> “Gold plating in the project means needlessly enhancing the expected results, namely, adding characteristics that are costly, not required, and that have low added value with respect to the targets ― in other words, giving more with no real justification other than ***to demonstrate*** one’s own talent.”

*source; ‘*Empowering Project Teams: Using Project Followership to Improve Performance*’ written by Marco Sampietro, Tiziano Villa

(1) While I think the ‘*other than*’ is a conjunction and so the parallel structure is required, are the ‘to infinitive’, ‘bare infinitive’, and ‘participle’ all allowed in the place of ‘***to demonstrate***’ above? (I guess a few words have been left out ahead of ‘*giving*’ as in “*in other words, (gold plating in the project means) giving more* . . .”)

(2) Is there any special grammar rule to determine the verb form after ‘*other than*’? Also, do we have to consider the case that the verb in main clause is ‘to do’ or not? Of course, I’ve seen the sentences below, which sometime allows ‘participle’;

> - *Ron has no choice other than **to opt** for the exam*.
> - *I was told I should be *doing* something other than **watching** TV*.

Will appreciate your responses.